# How prove this number equation $\sigma{(n)}=2n+1$ has no solution

Tags: number-theory

let $\sigma{(n)}$ is sums of the divisor function,

show that
$$\sigma{(n)}=2n+1$$ has no solution? Thank you

My try:I know this: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divisor_function

Comment: I think this is an open problem, but a lot might have happened since 1982. See the comment at: http://oeis.org/A033880

Comment: By the way, I don't mean to dissuade anyone from attempting this problem. Someone here might have a key insight.

Comment: @Casteels Ooops, hadn't seen your comment.

Answer (score 3):

Not a complete solution here, but at least we can reduce the number of possibilities.

If $n$ were a power of $2$, the result is obviously false as $\sigma(n) \leq n+n/2+n/4+\ldots = 2n$. So assume $n$ has at least one odd prime $q$ such that $q|n$.

Note that we have 
$$ \sigma(n) = \prod_{p|n} {\frac{p^{v_p(n)+1}-1}{p-1} } $$
where $v_p(n)$ is the greatest power of the prime $p$ that divides $n$.

We will look at the parity. When it comes to parity, the factor where $p=2$ (if it appears) is not important. We then have $\sigma(n)\equiv \prod_{p|n ; p\neq 2} (v_p(n)+1) (\bmod. 2)$. Simply because $\frac{p^{v_p(n)+1}-1}{p-1} = 1 + \ldots + p^{v_p(n)}$ which has $v_p(n)+1$ odd terms when the prime $p$ is odd.

So if $\sigma(n)$ were even, we know there is already no solution, as $2n+1$ is odd. Hence $v_p(n)$ has to be even for all odd primes $p|n$.

**Fact 1** Hence $ n = 2^k \cdot m^2$ where $m$ is an odd number.

Thus we have $$2^{k+1} m^2 + 1 = 2n+1 = \sigma(n) = \sigma(2^k)\sigma(m^2) = (2^{k+1}-1) \sigma(m^2)$$

this is nonsense if $k$ were odd, because, by looking at the equation in module $3$ we get:  $m^2 + 1 \equiv 0(\bmod. 3)$, and $-1$ is not a quadratic residue module 3. Thus $k$ is even, and $n$ is a square.

**Fact 2** $n$ is a perfect square.